# <SafeAreaView> not work (Views go above the notification tab)

Tags: react-native

For some reason safeAreaView does not work in my code, Views go above the notification tab. I've tried a few things but couldn't. I tried to take the style of safeAreaView and create a view below safeAreaView that involves all the code and then in that view put that style, but it didn't work either!

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View, Image, Text } from 'react-native';

export default function Menu({ navigation }){

    return <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.profile}>
            <Image source={{uri: 'https://elysator.com/wp-content/uploads/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280-e1523978675847.png'}} style={styles.imageProfile} />
            <Text style={styles.name}>StackOverFlow</Text>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
    },
    profile: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#EEE',
    },
    imageProfile: {
        width: 34,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginTop: 5,
        borderRadius: 44/2,
        marginLeft: 10,
        height: 34
    },
    name: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginLeft: 10,
        fontSize: 16
    }
});
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

According to react-native docs:

> The purpose of SafeAreaView is to render content within the safe area
> boundaries of a device. It is currently only applicable to iOS devices
> with iOS version 11 or later.

I would advise you to not just follow safeAreaView functionalities. rather its better extract the Status bar height and give a marginTop to whole container so its always below the status bar. See the code below and also the working expo snack solution:

```
import React from 'react';
import { SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, View, Image, Text,StatusBar } from 'react-native';

export default function Menu({ navigation }){

    return <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.profile}>
            <Image source={{uri: 'https://elysator.com/wp-content/uploads/blank-profile-picture-973460_1280-e1523978675847.png'}} style={styles.imageProfile} />
            <Text style={styles.name}>StackOverFlow</Text>
        </View>
    </SafeAreaView>
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    container: {
        flex: 1,
        marginTop:StatusBar.currentHeight
    },
    profile: {
        flexDirection: 'row',
        backgroundColor: '#EEE',
    },
    imageProfile: {
        width: 34,
        marginBottom: 5,
        marginTop: 5,
        borderRadius: 44/2,
        marginLeft: 10,
        height: 34
    },
    name: {
        alignSelf: 'center',
        marginLeft: 10,
        fontSize: 16
    }
});
```

Expo link :[expo-snack](https://snack.expo.io/SJ1wCQiCH)

Comment: `currentHeight` is only supported on Android.

Comment: Status.currentHeight returns null on iOS.

Answer (score 38):

The `react-native` version doesn't work on Android or early iOS versions.

Specifically you want to use:

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native-safe-area-context'
```

and not

```
import { SafeAreaView } from 'react-native'
```

If you're not already using [react-native-safe-area-context](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-safe-area-context) then you might want to read the documentation as it also requires that you use the `SafeAreaProvider` component at a higher level in your app.

Answer (score 26):

The `SafeAreaView` from `'react-native-safe-area-context'` just worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

Try "resizeMode" in imageview 
enum('cover', 'contain', 'stretch', 'repeat', 'center')

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image#resizemode

Answer (score 0):

SafeAreaView work fine with ios but not work with android , to solve it you can use expo-constants to add padding only at android devices

#### Step 1: Install expo-constants

```
npm install expo-constants
```

#### Step 2: Import expo-constants

```
import Constants from 'expo-constants'
```

#### Step 3: Apply this style to SafeAreaView

```
 saveAreaStyle:{
  paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
};
```

> **This padding will apply at android devices only**

### full code

```
  import {
  SafeAreaView,
  StyleSheet
} from "react-native";

import Constants from "expo-constants";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={styles.saveAreaStyle}>
     <Text>
        Hello World!
     </Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

export default App;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  saveAreaStyle: {
    paddingTop: Constants.statusBarHeight,
  },
});
```