# Why can't you fill full screen with View inside SafeAreaView?

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, flexbox, expo

## Code

```
export default function App() {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView style={{ flex: 1, backgroundColor: "orange" }}>
      <View style={{ position: "absolute", height: "100%", width: "100%", backgroundColor: "red" }} />
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
}
```

## Result

[image]

## Questions

1. How can I get the inner `View` to be full screen red without getting rid of `SafeAreaView`?
2. Why is the orange part there?

The reason for question 2, I would expect if I couldn't do this, I would see orange just outside the `SafeAreaView` (i.e. little slivers of orange outside of the "safe area") but instead I get this which puzzles me.

Comment: A really hacky way I can do this is `<View style={{ position: "absolute", height: "120%", top: -50, width: "100%", backgroundColor: "red" }} />` But I am not a fan

Answer (score 0):

I have checked your problem, but the difference between my code and yours is that my components are wrapped with the [@react-navigation/native](https://reactnavigation.org/) package.
so the result becomes:[my result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kpj6F.png)

to solve his issue you have these 2 options:

- Use @react-navigation/native package and wrap your components with this  as we will need navigation in our app
- check this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59428494/safeareaview-not-work-views-go-above-the-notification-tab)